# jQuery UI Progressbar direction change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-progressbar

The default direction of the jQuery UI Progressbar is from left to right. How do I change it so that it moves from right to left on completion? Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: right to left]

Answer (score 1):

CSS only, try adding this to your page:

```
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
  float: right;
}
```

This is not a complete answer, but a test to see if this is what you intended.

Comment: the js doesn't work and I don't see how starting at max would make the direction switch, let's say if I was 50%

Comment: @Julian try this new "solution"

Comment: perfect. had to float it "right" of course and add a bit of jquery "('.ui-corner-left').addClass('ui-corner-right').removeClass('ui-corner-left');" but it worked perfectly. Can't believe I didn't think of this before! Might want to change that to float : right for future reference for other users.

Comment: You probably want to be a little more narrowing than just .ui-corner-left for when you add something else in the future, but sweet.

Comment: How about a position:absolute;right:0; + classChange ui-corner-right. Any one who doent like to float can try it.

Comment: If it worked, sure would be lovely to collect another checkmark ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use CSS3 to rotate your progress bar 180 degrees:

```
#progressbar {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cP5SY/)

Not tested on older versions of IE.

Comment: nice, but I need ie7+ support

Comment: Ask users nicely to install [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) on their IE6-9. `:)`

Comment: i agree, the web would be a better place, but forcing users to install software to get a better viewing experience brings up bad memories of the the ActiveX days :)

Comment: @Julian Not going too off-topic, but "the ActiveX days"? Even nowadays IE9 asks me to allow blocked ActiveX content to access my own websites! Heh, anyway, here's a [CSS3 fully working fiddle even in IE6](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cP5SY/4/), GCF takes about 2 clicks to install only, a couple seconds to download, installs automatically and doesn't require a page reload. I'm not stressing myself with IE from now on. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same issue today with angular ui's progressbar. The other answers were close but didn't work in bootstrap 3 with out changing all instances which was not acceptable to me.

This worked... The selector gets the first child div and then applies the float

```
.progress-reverse div:nth-of-type(1) {
    float: right;
}
```

and

```
<progressbar class="progress-striped progress-reverse active" value="progress" type="{{progressType}}"></progressbar>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#progressbar-2" ).progressbar({
           isRTL: true,
           value: 30,
           max:300
        });
```